# what's the line meaning in javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

1. `if (document.all)`
2. `document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';`
3. `if (window.sidebar)`

What's those lines meaning in javascript? thank you.

Comment: please ignore the first one :)

Comment: Hi, you should provide a larger excerpt of the code for answers to be really useful.

Comment: i think this edit is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don’t use document.all:

```
if (document.all) {
   element = document.all[id];
else {
   element = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

1. document.all was introduced in Internet Explorer 4, because the W3C DOM hadn’t yet standardised a way of grabbing references to elements using their ID.
   By the time IE 5 came out, document.getElementById() had been standardised and as a result, IE 5 included support for it.
   [More info here.](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll/).
2. `document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'` is used to set current page as home page in the IE.
3. `if (window.sidebar)` is a check for firefox

Comment: @zhuanzhou This is explanation, why and when this check came into the world.

Comment: thank you, got it. what's this line meaning? document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';

Comment: @zhuanzhou 4 Oh, sorry. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
document.all is used to check if the browser is IE
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (document.all)`: used to check if the brower is IE, but note this is [bad practice](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#all) because it is no longer a good method of doing the test.

`if (window.sidebar)`: test if the browser is Firefox.

EDIT: `document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';` is most likely used [to set the homepage when the browser is IE](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/make-homepage.html). However, [it does not seem to work well with Firefox and the others](http://www.coderanch.com/t/504770/HTML-JavaScript/Make-Default-Homepage).

Comment: got it, thank you,waht's this line meaning? document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';

Answer (score 1):

Statement 1 tries to detect if the browser is IE and statement 2 uses an IE-only API: [behavior property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, document.all is not IE-only feature. It also exists on Chromium/Chrome and other WebKit based browsers.

Therefore, statement 1 get passed on IE & Chrome, but statement 2 only works on IE.